# I need a Stored Procedure that is not part of the calling transaction

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I have created a library of native-compiled routines, memory optimized tables, roles, event handler, etc.   It all works amazing...   UNTIL the caller of the routines has a transaction started.

My library needs to be ..  is Autonomous the right word...?  ....   Independant....?

The library needs to be able to control its tables completely separate of any transactions going on in the calling code.  It makes entries in the tables (including a logging table) and these need to be **immediately** available to any other session.  And all of the entries need to **remain** no matter if the caller Aborts their own transaction.

As an example, I have used the sp_getapplock set of routines before.   Whatever mechanism they are using for keeping track of the locks is not affected by transactions.

Comment: You are going to need a loopback connection with SQLCLR. Although I'd love to know your use case, it seems unusual

Comment: _library needs to be able to control its tables completely separate_ which contradicts the entire idea of ACID. I suggest your design just won't work within the database engine as you intend. If you need autonomy, then it seems you need a design similar to service broker where the sql process simply "requests" an action which is then run asynchronously from the "requestor". But that approach contradicts the "immediately available" point. Quite a design / architecture pickle you have.

Comment: quick summary, @Charlieface, is I am making an alternative to sp_getapplock due to its **very** limited range (32-bit hash) causing lock conflicts in my product.  I posted a different question weeks ago; but some admin closed it saying it didn't have enough details.  Anyway, there is no combination of strings you can pass to getapplock which will change the collision probability.  My case is perhaps different than others' due to hundreds of locks which may remain open indefinitely in a large system.  So if there is a conflict on one of those (there was!) the app can *never* complete its task.

Comment: Hi @Smor
I actually had that same suggestion come up elsewhere.  
The steps currently taken are basically just an insert on a table and check @@rowcount or exception from unique key conflict -- so it is very fast.
The suggestion was to move that into a Queue Listener and have the caller wait for that to be done.

Comment: I would suggest, looking at your use case, that a complete rethink is needed. Perhaps you should have all calls go via middleware, such as an application/web server, which controls these locks (they can still be stored in the DB), and all SQL has to go via that. So the server can control the placing of the locks, and ensure they are committed before anything else happens.